# Does Real time section in Google Analytics work with Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, cordova-plugins

I've created a mobile app with cordova, and installed the GA plugin, the trackEvent function seem to work with success.
But now, after 2 hours, I see nothing in the real time overview / events, and nothing in Behavior -> Events of GA.

I've read the it can take up to a day for the stats to be shown, but I see nothing (for few hours) in the real time section (0 active users, and events).

Does the real time work for mobile apps?
How long am I supposed to wait?
If I get no errors, and I'm sure my GA id is good, what is the next step for debugging?
thanks

Comment: New google analytics accounts can take 48 -72 hours to start showing data even in real-time.   When did you create the account?

Comment: hey, I just created the account.

Comment: Actually, I just created another account, the first one (that doesnt seem to work) was a WEB account, I just created a new mobile account, and now I can see some traffic. I'll check if it works, and update the topic.

Comment: There is a difference between web accounts and application accounts.  Mainly one shows Pageviews the other shows screenviews.   While you can send screenviews to a web google analytics account the google analytics website wont show you the data since its set up to only show pageviews on a web account and vice versa.

Comment: How do you access the RTD? I've already written an application which shows the RTD inside and outside the application. You can set the interval inside the settings and choose the account from which you want the RTD to be displayed.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have same issue.

Comment: @sambhavgore hey,yes please read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It does work, and it's immediat.
Needed to define a mobile app in google, and i had some bugs in my code.
Dont forget to disable the filters in google.
And get the newest version pf thr GA plugin.